# mysql sum results after each sum

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm trying to sum the result of two mysql result.

This is my code, it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
     a.* ,
    b.* , 
    SUM(b.price) as price,
    SUM(b.tax) as tax,
    price + tax as price_tax --> error
FROM (SELECT  name , item_id 
     FROM items)a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_id , price , tax
         FROM bank
        )b
ON a.item_id = b.item_id 
GROUP BY item_id
```

- I want to sum the two results like this: `price + tax` as `price_tax`

Comment: Which error do you get? Pls add it to the question

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First

The SQL engine don't know the  column alias in select clause during (the specific) query execution so
you can't use alias  you must repeat the code

```
      SELECT 

        SUM(b.price) as price,
        SUM(b.tax) as tax,
        SUM(b.price) +  SUM(b.tax) as  price_tax 
        FROM (
            SELECT  name , item_id 
            FROM items
        )a
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT item_id , price , tax

        FROM bank
        )b
        ON a.item_id = b.item_id 
        GROUP BY item_id
```

Second

in some mysql version is not allowed  the use of aggregation function and select column not mentioned  in group by  so  you must remove the column not mention in group by  (or add fake aggreation function ) for the others columns

```
      SELECT 
        a.item ,
        SUM(b.price) as price,
        SUM(b.tax) as tax,
        SUM(b.price) +  SUM(b.tax) as  price_tax 
        FROM (
            SELECT  name , item_id 
            FROM items
        )a
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT item_id , price , tax

        FROM bank
        )b
        ON a.item_id = b.item_id 
        GROUP BY item_id
```